# Setting order of ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

1. 

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("black"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

2. 

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("black"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

I wonder which one is the correct order ?thanks

Comment: It shouldn't really matter.  Are you seeing problems with one vs the other?

Comment: Nope , but I think the first one is more logical to set the color and after that the display in a way ? not sure

Comment: There's no technical reason to prefer one or the other, but I agree that its nicer from a readability perspective to keep the changes to the drawable in one spot and the setting of the action bar in another.